# How i can add jdk to dependencies in enclojure-project?

Tags: netbeans, clojure, enclojure

Netbeans 6.9.1, Enclojure (Netbeans's GUI question)

I want to use standard java libraries in my clojure code (e.g swing), but project's folder 'Libraries' contains clojure's dependencies only (3 jars). How I can add jdk to this dependencies if it wasn't added automatically?

UPD: my mistake, ok. i mean...
 How I can view jdk structure (classes) in project tree? Or somewhere in netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Those are part of the JRE, and will be available from any Java program whether you like it or not. You don't have to do anything special to get them.

Comment: But how i can view jdk tree (libraries and classes)?

Answer (score 0):

Responding to you comment to amalloy's answer, in the Project window, under Libraries, it will list the JDK version you are using. You can expand that to show the JARs included. You can then expand individual JARs to show the classes included. (I verified this with NetBeans 7, but recall that it worked the same way on 6.9.)

Comment: JDK is visible in Java projects, but not in Enclojure project (and in all Maven-projects). I asked how to make it visible.